# How to return a widget from fumction with animation

Tags: function, flutter, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a function that based on some conditions returns different widgets, for example in a screen first returns widget A and when some conditions change it returns widget B , but  I want it to be with animations even basic one like when navigating between material routes.

```
Widget decider() {
    if (some condition) {
        return widgetA;
    } else {
        return widgetB;   
    }  
}
```

Comment: you have to pass the reference to decider -   ```child: decider``` (omit "()")

Comment: @RubensMelo I know that but they  don't change  with animation , they just vanish

Comment: It's a but too broad. What animation do you want?

Comment: @RémiRousselet whatever, fade animation is OK.